# ssh error with publickey for normal user

Tags: ssh

I know that ssh problems were already discussed here still before down-vote this question, please, read. :-)

I have two freshly installed *virtually* equal servers under CentOS 6. They are used in *DRBD/HA* environment. All settings on both of them, AFAIK, are the same. Most of them where copied with *rsync*.

I can log-in as root with my key being accepted to both servers; however I can log-in as normal user only on one of them (*master1*).

Some more info.

**User**: 
The permissions on users *home-directory* and his *.ssh* are 700. The files: authorized_keys, id_dsa, id_rsa are 600. Whole structure of */HOME* is exactly the same on both machines (rsynced).

**Configuration**: 
GSSAPI, Kerberos and PAM are deactivated. sshd_config and ssh_config files are exactly the same on both machines (rsynced). The same is true for */etc/hosts*, */etc/passwd*, */etc/group*, */etc/shadow*, network settings (except IPs and MACs), running services (except that these started with *heartbeat* are not running on *master2*)...

A try to loggin as a user xxxx from *master1* to *master2* looks like:

```
ssh -v master2
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to master2 [XXX.XXX.XX.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'master2' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/xxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxxx/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
xxxx@master2's password:
```

Now comes the fun:

I've started the sshd in debug/non-forking mode (in temp_sshd I've changed port to 12345):

```
cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config ~/temp_sshd_config
vi  ~/temp_sshd_config
/usr/sbin/sshd -f ~/temp_sshd_config -dd
```

Than loggin as normal user works with public-key:

```
ssh -v -p 12345 master2
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to master2 [XXX.XXX.XX.2] port 12345.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug1: Host 'master2' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/xxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: found matching key w/out port
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxxx/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Last login: Wed Feb 29 15:06:25 2012 from master1
```

As I want to set *PasswordAuthentication NO* in *sshd*, I need to have public-key loggin running.

Any help most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please show/examine ssh *server*'s log (`/var/log/secure`) at *master2* as well. Since it's the server who decides whether to accept the public key, the answer should be there.

Personally, I suspect it has something to do with SELinux context (not copied by rsync without `-X`).

Comment: You were right. I was sure that I disabled SELinux on both nodes, but I was wrong. I did it only on master1. Thank you!

Unfortunately I can't vote-up your answer. Once again thanks.

Comment: You can check it as the chosen answer instead...